# How to get an entity between two dates in appengine datastore for

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, datastore

I have an appointment table with appointment date as one of the columns. I want to retrieve all the appointments between two dates in appengine datastore using JPA. can please let me know how to achieve this? I tried with following query but it did not work.

select a from Appointment a where (apptSts='p' or apptSts='a') and (apptDate>=:fromDate or apptDate<=:toDate)

Comment: Did any of the answers help you?

Comment: Yes..the one right below here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To retrieve appointments between 2 dates, you need to change your query logic to include "**and**" instead of "**or**" :

```
select a from Appointment
where apptDate>=fromDate and apptDate<=toDate
```

You CAN have inequality filers on the same property in appengine, but they can't be combined with OR.

See examples in [gql reference](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference#Examples), which should also apply to JPA.

Answer (score 3):

Make the property as a list property.  Then you can query between two dates.
See the following test code done in Objectify.  I think you can use the same technique in JPA also.
https://github.com/stickfigure/objectify/blob/master/src/test/java/com/googlecode/objectify/test/QueryExoticTypesTests.java

Answer (score 0):

You can apply multiple inequality but they should be on the same field (variable).I guess whats going wrong here is that app engine doesn't allow to use the bracket things ,,,i mean

```
(conditionA AND conditionB .....) OR (conditionC AND conditionC .....)
//--this is not allowed.
```

By the way following is allowed(i tried it)

```
(conditionA AND conditionB .....) AND (conditionC AND conditionC)
//--allowed(although its bracket are meaning less here)
```

Answer (score -3):

You can only do one greater than or less than query, so one way to do it is to do a greater than query, and walk through the results and manually filter out the ones that don't match the less than query.

Comment: isn't there any other simplest way? Why is it not supported. This kind of requirement is very basic and it must be supported.

Comment: I am getting the following error message...................... SEVERE: org.datanucleus.store.appengine.query.DatastoreQuery$UnsupportedDatastoreFeatureException: Problem with query <SELECT FROM Appointment a WHERE a.busnId=10001 and a.staffId=10001 and (apptSts='p' or apptSts='a') and apptDate>=:fromDate or apptDate<=:toDate>: 'or' filters can only check equality

Comment: It isn't supported.  Read the query docs, the limitation of having only one inequality is pretty clearly stated.  If you need richer queries try another database.  You can use CloudSQL if you really want to stick with GAE.

Comment: My entire application is in datastore...I cannot migrate it to any other database for now. can you please suggest me more effective work around for it?

Comment: I think that is the way to do it.  Might be a bit easier if you apply a sortorder.  You can come up with more creative ways to do it too, like query for each day indpendently and merge the results yourself.

Comment: You can do greater than or less than on the SAME property in appengine.